# Using SQL rollback after a test case, but the method being tested uses commit

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, junit, automated-tests

I am trying to write a unit test for one of our app's database access methods. We have a dedicated test database (a periodic dump/copy of the live database). Normally each test case is run in a single transaction, and rolled back afterwards. We accomplish this by using `Connection.setAutoCommit(false)` before the test case, and `Connection.rollback()` afterwards.

But this time, I'm trying to write a test for a method which itself does everything as one transaction, and uses `Connection.commit()` at the end.

Is there a way I can keep the `commit` from actually committing to the database without throwing an error in the method being tested? That is, how can I keep this test case from really altering the test DB's contents?

Notes: Using Java, JDBC, and Junit. `java.sql.Connection` is used for database connections, and `java.sql.PreparedStatement` is used for running queries.

The @Before and @After code:

```
/**
 * Obtain a new connection and set autoCommit to false.
 * This lets us run a test case then revert all of the changes
 * so the test cases don't interfere with each other.
 */
@Before
public void initConnection() {
    conn = Database.getConnection();
    try {
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("Unable to set connection AutoCommit=false");
    }
}

/**
 * Rollback the changes made by the test case
 * and close the connection.
 */
@After
public void rollbackConnection() {
    try {
        conn.rollback();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("Unable to rollback");
    }
    Database.closeConnection(conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to do this?  If you're writing a proper test, you'd likely like to verify that the data indeed has been committed and conforms to whatever you're trying to accomplish.  If you're worried about the changes, clean them up when finished.

If there really is a valid reason, however, you could remove the transaction (txn) code, write a helper function that wraps the function call in a transaction and have clients call that helper function and the test code call the original.  This is likely not the best way to go about it, but an option.

Comment: You don't need to commit to test & confirm the changes, you just need to use the same connection for whatever load code is used to confirm the changes, prior to rolling back.

Comment: @MartinCarney - Then the test isn't really testing the database, just the logic of the code in isolation.  If you have a test database, there's no reason you shouldn't be committing, and you run into problems like this where your code has to be adapted to the test case, not the other way around.  Just use an in memory database or a set of mocks if you just want to test the logic, but you're opening yourself to probelms down the line.

Answer (score 0):

Asked my office-mates if they had any ideas. One suggested mocking it (using Mockquito), which led me to a slightly better alternative. I'm creating a wrapper for `Connection` that extends `Connection` and acts like the normal connection, but when its transaction-related methods are used, it behaves differently.

In production, a normal `Connection` is used, and for test cases, this wrapper class will be used.

Specifically:

- It starts a real transaction when it is instantiated at the beginning of each test case.
- When it is told to set autocommit to false (normally how we start a long transaction), it creates a `Savepoint` and holds on to it
- When it is told to commit, it releases the old `Savepoint` and gets a new one.
- When it is told to rollback, it rolls back to the `Savepoint`.
- Setting autocommit to true when it was set to false releases the `Savepoint`.
- If it is told to set a `Savepoint` (which is supposed to start a transaction if none was in progress), it starts a fake transaction as above in addition to setting the requested `Savepoint`.
- At the end of the test case, the real transaction is rolled back.

These changes allow it to act like it's in a transaction for the methods it is testing that use transactions, while keeping the whole thing revertable after the test case finishes.

PS - If there's something I should be doing but am not, let me know so I can improve the wrapper class.